# How to select machines and users that have only w10 compatible apps

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have spent most of my career learning the data platform with sql however I want to get more involved with querying.   I am making my own scenarios and attempting to pull data out of tables I have created but I am hitting s wall.  Apologies this is probably simplistic query but I am hoping you can enlighten me as to what I am doing incorrectly and to provide assistance.  The Premise is I have a list of PCs that I want to rebuild but only based on if all apps that are installed on them are windows 10 compatible.

I have a few tables.
Tbl_Windows_7_PCs
Fields are 
MachineName
IPAddress
AssignedUser
Application

Now this table shows multiple rows it has no primary key. An example is as follows

```
Pc001    10.0.0.20   Joe Bloggs     Ms Word 2016
Pc001    10.0.0.20   Joe Bloggs     Ms Excel 2016
Pc001    10.0.0.20   Joe Bloggs     Ms Access 2016
Pc002    10.0.0.34   Jane Smith     Ms Excel 2016
Pc002    10.0.0.34   Jane Smith     Sage
Pc002    10.0.0.34   Jane Smith     Adobe Acrobat
```

I have another table called Windows Compatible Aplications

Once again no primary key

Tbl_Win10_Compatible_Apps

Fields are but one

Application

Values are
MS Excel 2016
Sage
Adobe Acrobat

So I want to produce a query that selects only the machine name and the assigneduser from tbl_Windows_7_PCs Where all applications that are installed are present in Tbl_Win10_Compatible_Apps.

The kicker is I don’t want to pull back all of the rows I just want to show the machine and user (singular) if that makes sense.

As I am learning would appreciate if anyone has the solution to explain how they arrived at the solution.

Comment: Please, change the title of your question which must reflect what you need.

Comment: I down-vote and flag it because no efforts from OP's side.

Comment: This sounds like a simple `join`.

Comment: You could check `distinct MachineName, AssignedUser` for `where not exists` an application that _isn't_ in the Windows 10 blessings table. Of course if there happened to be more than one `AssignedUser` for a `MachineName` ... .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I think it wouldn't be bad idea to add a primary key to those tables with an [IDENTITY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property).

But I think you're looking for something like this query.

It's simple LEFT JOIN with a GROUP BY and a HAVING.

```
SELECT w7pc.MachineName, w7pc.AssignedUser
FROM Tbl_Windows_7_PCs w7pc
LEFT JOIN Tbl_Win10_Compatible_Apps w10apps
  ON w10apps.Application = w7pc.Application
GROUP BY w7pc.MachineName, w7pc.AssignedUser
HAVING COUNT(w7pc.Application) = COUNT(w10apps.Application)
```

For the w7pc that don't match with a w10apps record, the w10apps.Application will be empty. A count by value doesn't count the empty. So only if they all match the 2 counts will be equal.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I think the Question title has already been changed by someone so hopefully will get more response.  I will run what you have suggested and feed back and let you know if I have any issues

Comment: Absolutely fantastic.  this is exactly what i was looking for.  Had to modify some of my datatypes as they were both text but after that it worked like a dream.

Comment: This Query helped me out alot.  To summarise it pulls back all machines where all records for a machine are present in the W10APPS.  How would i phrase it so i could pull back all machines that dont?

Comment: @Wex That should be easy. Just replace the `=` by `<>` or by `!=` because then the counts wouldn't be equal. And add the counts also to the select to see how much they differ.